# Independent layout from screen orientation

Tags: android

I want to make independent layout from screen orientation.

Something like this:

[image: http://cs302715.userapi.com/v302715020/1953/RK2fHUV7svY.jpg]
<sub>(source: [userapi.com](http://cs302715.userapi.com/v302715020/1953/RK2fHUV7svY.jpg))</sub>

Comment: you want to keep the layout unchanged immaterial of the orientation right?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you will have to draw those yourself as custom widgets. I seem to recall somebody creating a `TextView` subclass that wrote vertically.

Comment: I want to make this buttons look like they are in landspace mode , when screen is in portrait mode.

Comment: You could use a floatingactionbutton for this on each side of the screen.  they can automatically center on each side and can also be rotated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so what you want has nothing to do with the landscape mode, you just want the button text such that it seems that those are in landscape mode. I can suggest something which is kind of a hack.

For that you can have the buttons as usual with more height and less width and align them with left and the right edge of the screen.

For button text you need to make a .jpg or a .png of your text, rotate it and set that as the background for the button.(if you change button text dynamically then you need other snaps of text). This wont look good but it is one of the ways to do what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you want to have seperate layout files for portrait and landscape views ?
Then you should create two different files each in layout and layout-land directory under res.

```
res
 |_ layout
 |_ layout-land
```

Android will call the appropriate layout based on the device configuration.

To retain the data, you may use

```
 @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();       
        return bundle;
    }
```

and get the bundle in onCreate()

```
final Bundle savedBundle = (Bundle)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
```

Comment: No, I want to make 2 buttons which will look like they are in landspace mode , but the screen will be in portrait mode. It will look like at this picture - 3 buttonts in portrait mode, 2 buttons in landspace mode when phone in Portrait mode.

Comment: Do you want help with the layout xml code? or you want help with retaining the layout on landscape